# Optimization with many (repetitive) constraints

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, constraints, svm

I am looking to solve an SVM problem using optimization techniques in Python.

I am having issues figuring out a way to enter constraints efficiently into the `scipy.optimize.minimize` command. I have 120 constraints that are the same function but use different array inputs. I wrote code that acts like an indicator function if each of these constraints is met, but the `minimize()` function does not recognize it. Is there a less DYI method that I am missing?

For example, I could enter:
`f(x1) =< 0, ... , f(xn) =< 0` where the parameters are arrays of length 10,
but was looking for a cleaner approach.

Comment: It seems that the constraints argument in minimize function is a sequence of dict items and each dict item is a single constraint. may be writing a list comprehension  to create those dicts may provide the solution.